# Angular 5 how to get value of tag input

Tags: angular, angular5

In HTML, I have used tag input. Users can type comma separated values there.  Howver, in `.ts`, I'm unable to get the values of tag input. Below what I coded in html and the ts file separately:

```
<tag-input name="users" [(ngModel)]="users"></tag-input>
```

in .ts file -

```
onSubmit(form : NgForm) {
console.log(form.value);
}
```

It shows `{users: undefined, message: "my message"}`

How can I get the value of users field on submit?

Comment: where you have consoled `users`?

Comment: @PardeepJain as  stated above, under `onSubmit`. I mean, the form values includes users.

Comment: in the function you have consoled `form.value` not `users` please check

Comment: @PardeepJain I mean, the form values includes users. and its showed undefined

Comment: {users: undefined, message: "my message"}

Comment: But you have not bind with `formControlName` to get in form value, you have bind with ngModel only, simplt try to console `this.users`

Comment: How can I do it, ? means bind the field with `formControlName` ?

Comment: I tried as you suggested like this.users but it still shows `undefined`

Comment: please post your code on stackblitz I'll check

Comment: what is your `this.users` type ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tag-input?file=app%2Fapp.component.html @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara might help you

Comment: Its my fault as I have not understand about tag input. I should press enter after completing an email. Now its working.

Comment: import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: Great @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara #HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

In .ts file you need to define "users" variable inside class

```
public users: String = '';
```

Now you can directly access this variable inside onSubmit()

```
onSubmit(form : NgForm) {
   console.log(this.users);
}
```

If you want to use form then need to define the following code

```
//.ts file
public testForm:FormGroup; 
constructor( public fb:FormBuilder){}
ngOnInit(){
   this.testForm= new fb.group({
      users: [''];
   });
}
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.testForm);
}

//.html file
<form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" formControlName="users" [(ngModel)]="users" [value]="users"/>
   <input type="submit"/>Click
</form>
```

Maybe this demo code helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get data without `ngForm`.

```
<tag-input name="users" [(ngModel)]="users.name"></tag-input>
```

In `.ts` file.

```
var users : any = {};

onSubmit(){
  console.log(users.name)
}
```